# UITabBarItem don't show any icon images?

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have this code:

```
 MeuPrimeiroViewController *primeiro = [[MeuPrimeiroViewController alloc] init];
    MeuSegundoViewController *segundo = [[MeuSegundoViewController alloc]init];

    UITabBarController *tabbar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    tabbar.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:primeiro,segundo, nil];

    primeiro.tabBarItem.title = @"Primeiro";
    primeiro.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"];
    segundo.tabBarItem.title = @"Segundo";
    segundo.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.jpg"];


    self.window.rootViewController = tabbar;
```

I don't know why, the images don't show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the  tabBarItem `initWithTitle:image:selectedImage` method instead. See the method definition [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html).